# Why is the volume scatter more dense in the viewport than in my final render?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, 3d-view, volumetrics

I need to get the same effect as in the viewport, but I can't find a difference in the settings for viewport and final render. All lights are render-activated in the outliner, and in the object properties. Thanks for any help

[image] (I changed the green color a little, so it's not 100% as in the images provided)

[image: Viewport]

[image: Final Render]

Comment: Thanks for looking into it, I appended the blend file to the post :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try setup like below.[image]

Then adjust "density" and mix shader fac.
Then what You also can do is to power up your lights.

Comment: thanks, this helped a lot indeed. I'm just wondering why there's the discrepancy between preview and render without the absorption shader in the first place.